# Looking for the proverb "Parents work hard, our life is so comfortable that children become beggar"

Tags: proverbs

I heard the following proverb that was said from Japanese (if not Chinese).

> If our parents are working too hard, our life becomes very convenient up to a point that causes their grandchildren become beggars.

Is there such a proverb in Japanese? If yes, what is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a well-known one, but we have.

- [親【おや】苦【く】、子【こ】楽【らく】、孫【まご】乞食【こじき】](http://www.kakeibo.biz/proverb/2007/03/post_12.html) "Parents toil, children ease, grandchildren beg."

  Also with many variations:

  - [祖父【じじ】は辛労【しんろう】、子は楽、孫は乞食](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%A5%96%E7%88%B6%E3%81%AF%E8%BE%9B%E5%8A%B4%E5%AD%90%E3%81%AF%E6%A5%BD%E5%AD%AB%E3%81%AF%E4%B9%9E%E9%A3%9F-519015)
  - [「親苦労、子楽、孫ほいと」「親苦労、子楽、孫潰」「親苦労、子楽、孫貧乏」 etc.](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/eigakun/e/6ac186813b794243080b70778a3cddc2)
  - [親‌草鞋【わらじ】、倅【せがれ】草履【ぞうり】で、孫‌雪駄【せった】、曾孫【ひまご】の代には裸足【はだし】なりけり](https://www.amazon.co.jp/review/R3NSDV9OC7M32H)
    "parents (wear) sandals, kids shoes, grandchildren boots, great-grandchildren would become bare feet"

But more famous sayings with similar moral are:

- [児孫【じそん】のために美田【びでん】を買わず](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/97283/meaning/m0u/)
- [売り家と唐様【からよう】で書く三代目【さんだいめ】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/20962/meaning/m0u/)

Comment: すごい、1つも知らなかったです…ｗ

Comment: @naruto ま、まぐれだと思います（汗